# Hide Heatmap DataLabels based on Condition

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

how to hide datalabels of a heatmap based on condition i.e. i want to hide all the datalabels which are (==0 or <50). As there is a bug in Highcharts api, when ever i restore the browser the zero's show up in unusual order.
[Bug Link](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3295)

As of now i found a workaround replacing 0 with '0' but i dont want to show that on the heatmap. Here is the fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/234/) , in fiddle its working but when implemented on application it's replicating that bug.

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40,
            plotBackgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 1, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0.03, 'rgb(247, 88, 45)'],
                    [0.5, 'rgb(255, 224, 80)'],
                    [0.67, 'rgb(54, 64, 207)'],
                    [0.99, 'rgb(13, 163, 35)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(217, 186, 50']
                ]
            }
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Insignificant', 'Minimum', 'Significant', 'Material', 'Critical']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['< 1%', '2-10%', '11-50%', '51-90%', '91-100%'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: 'transparent',
            maxColor:'transparent'
            //maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0,0,0],[0,1, 0],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],[2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],[3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],[4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none'
                }
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

I'm using Jasper studio the workaround snippet is

```
series.dataLabels.formatter:{function(){ if(this.point.value == 0) { return '0';} else { return this.point.value;}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples way is using [datalabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) which allows to add condition.

```
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            dataLabels:{
                formatter:function(){

                    if(this.point.value >=50)
                        return this.point.value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/246/

Comment: hi Sebastian, i tried this solution earlier, this is a drilldown chart so when i'm clicking on empty space/cell it is giving me a "null uri" exception. I'm using it in jasper studio. so the workaround i thought is, to display labels based on condition when condition fails make label color transparent/none.... so that it wont give me that exception....

Comment: yeah Sebastian, i did that, the exception i'm getting is from jasper. So the work around would be to render datalabels, based on condition make the datalabels transparent. I'm unable to replicate the same exception in jsfiddle.... so can u help in making "datalabels transparent" on condition.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/247/) , just have a look at it, you'll get an idea of what i wanted to achieve....